# No carga los datos la primera vez en Angular5

Tags: angular

Al pulsar en un botón debería obtener los datos, pero tengo que pulsarlo 2 veces.

Aquí llamo a getPeople() para obtener un array con los datos y después llamo a getPerson() en el servicio conexion-person-service;

```
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

    detailPerson: Person; 
    @Input() id;


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conexion: ConexionPersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.conexion.getPeople();
        this.getPerson();
    }

    getPerson(): void {  
        this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(this.id);   
        console.log('al final obtengo' , this.detailPerson );    
     }
}
```

En el servicio conexion-person-service: Obtengo el Array con las personas,
además tengo el console log "ANTESOBTENIDO" que dará undefined la primera vez

```
@Injectable()
export class ConexionPersonService {

    _people: Person[];

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) { } 


    public getPeople() {

        const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json'; 
        this.http.get<Person[]>(url).subscribe(data => {this._people = data});
        console.log('ANTESobtenido ' , this._people);//aqui
    }

    public getPerson(id:number): Person{

        console.log('ID ' , id);

        if(this._people) {
            var per = this._people.find(person => person.id_user == id);
            console.log('obtenido ' , per);
            return this._people.find(person => person.id_user == id);
        }
    } 

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la img la primera vez que le doy no funciona, la siguiente vez que le doy click ya me saca los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código final:

El problema que siempre tuve fue como pasar la variable que se obtiene del subscribe al método de getPerson , probé con this con this.that. y un montón de cosas... , pero he visto que con { puedo llamar directamente a la función y pasarle la variable directamente. }

```
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

    detailPerson: Person;
    @Input() id;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conexion: ConexionPersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.conexion.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
            this.getPerson(data)
        }); //llamar aquí a getPerson recogiendo el subscribe
    }

    getPerson(data): void {
        this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(data,this.id);
        console.log('al final obtengo', this.detailPerson);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Injectable()
export class ConexionPersonService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }


    public getPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
        const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json';
        return this.http.get<Person[]>(url)
    }

    public getPerson(data, id: number) {
        var per = data.find(person => person.id_user == id);
        return data.find(person => person.id_user == id);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes pensar que el subscribe es un método asíncrono, así que es muy probable que al cargar la primera vez aún no tengas datos, y las siguientes veces estes usando datos cargados de la anterior vez.

Lo que deberías hacer es que el servicio retorne la promesa y esta se ejecute en el componente

```
 public getPeople() {
        const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json'; 

        return this.http.get(url)

        console.log('ANTESobtenido ' , this._people);//aqui
    }

getPerson(): void {  
        this.conexion.getPerson(this.id).subscribe(data => {
                this.detailPerson = data
                console.log('al final obtengo' , this.detailPerson );    
        });   

}
```

Comment: Antes tenía public getPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {  this.http.get<Person[]>(url).subscribe(data => {this._people = data}); }pero da error porque no retorna nada. Y tampoco sé que tengo que retornar

Comment: tienes que retornar el observable, como te he puesto en el mensaje return this.http.get<Person[]>(url) y en el getPeople() ejecutar el subscribe con lo que te retorna getPeople()

Comment: Poniendo tu código en getPerson(): da error el .subscribe : "la propiedad 'subscribe ' no existe en el tipo Person"

Comment: Prueba usando return this.http.get(url) sin el <Person[]>

Comment: No sé si eres consciente pero en getPerson(), está la llamada a la conexion.getPerson, pero tú has puesto el código de getPeople()

Comment: public getPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
  const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json';
  return this.http.get<Person[]>(url)
 } ya no funciona ni con 2000 clicks

Comment: A ver, te he puesto un ejemplo para mostrarte el tema de las llamadas asincronia. En el código que has pegado no tienes ningun console.log() para que te muestre nada.  Y el problema lo tienes ya que tienes las salidas te texto fuera de las llamadas. 

Para solucionarlo, como ya te he dicho, el servicio debe retornar el observable ya sea return this.http.get(url). Si llamas al método getPerson fuera del subscribe estarás en la misma situación que el console.log. No tienes las información que estás buscando

Comment: gracias, me has dado muchas ideas para poder resolverlo.Ya está